# CSS On hover dynamically width background image

Tags: javascript, css, hover

I am attempting to create a mouse-over effect on a navigation on my website.
The navigation is a horizontal bar with a few items in it. Code for it below;

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Our work and portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

This has a plain background color and between every `<li>` is a border to separate the items. Now I want to give a background image on hover, though my problem is that - as you can see - every `<li>` has a different width because of its contents and my image for the hover is as below;

[image: hover effect]

So it's actually just a black shadow on the left and right. The right shadow must be placed on the absolute right side of the `<li>` and the left shadow on the absolute left.

Is there any way to achieve this? Not a problem if it's with jQuery or anything like that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It'd be helpful to see the styles applied.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the shadow, and the variable length effect. Then split the image into three parts. And update your markup to something like this

1. Left Shadow
2. Center Part
3. Right Shadow

Then use the following CSS snippet

```
li a:hover:before { content: url("image/leftshadow.jpg"); }
li a:hover { background-Image: url("image/center.jpg"); }
li a:hover:after { content: url("image/rightshadow.jpg"); }
```

Comment: Classic [Sliding Doors](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/) technique only requires 2 images and has been refined by many to [only use one image](http://kailoon.com/css-sliding-door-using-only-1-image/)

Comment: Links are correct since the OP is only using the image for `:hover`, but [here's part II](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors2/) at ALA which covers combining the `:hover` and default images.

Answer (score 0):

Your image looks like a [linear gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/linear-gradient), so you could try using

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #111, #333, #111);
```

You may want to add support for older browsers.